# Display dataset in Horizontal bar with offset in the Excel?

Tags: excel, charts, offset

I have the following table

`Start               End             Duration (years)`
`Bob Larkin     September 1, 1924   October 1, 1932         8`
`Ed Jenkins     January 1, 1925     September 1, 1943       18`
`Speed Dash     March 15, 1925      March 1, 1930           4`
`Old Walrus     January 20, 1926    May 5, 1927             1`
`Lester Leith   January 1, 1929     June 1, 1943            14`
`Bob Zane       June 7, 1930        July 21, 1934           4`

I'd like to generate a horizontal bar chart with starting points for the bars according to their respective start date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel represents dates as days since 1900. If you create a stacked bar chart for the start dates and the duration in days you get 2 bars for each person: one from the lower limit of the horizontal axis (1900-1-1) to the start date and another one from the start date to the end date. Make the the first ones invisible.

After some tweaking of the axes (set limits of horizontal axis to 8767 and 15950, and revert vertical axis) I get this:

[image: chart]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Excellent !! Did you do this with a VBA script or by tweaking the bar properties?

Comment: I changed the properties by hand.

Comment: If you think my answer is helpful you could upvote it or mark it as accepted answer.